# FileNotFound exception when calling a SOAP WebService

Tags: c#, soap-client, xmlserializer

I developed a console application in C# that should call a Web Service method.

After I added the service reference and VS created the Proxy classes, I could use this to call the method:

```
        var seed = new Seed.CrSeedClient();
        string semilla = await seed.getSeedAsync();
```

When getSeedAsync method is called, this is shown in the debug window and, of course, the method does not return what it should.

```
'ConComm.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConComm.exe): 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' loaded. Module was compiled with no symbols.
Thrown exception: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Thrown exception: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'ConComm.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConComm.exe): 'C:\Users\jaime\AppData\Local\Temp\wcu5wg4c\wcu5wg4c.dll' loaded. Symbols loaded.
```

I have used steps explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/823196/prb-you-receive-a-system-io-filenotfoundexception-error-when-the-clien) to try to solve the problem.

First, I set

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

in app.manifest file to force the console application to run as administrator.

Second, I added this in app.config file:

```
  <system.diagnostics>         
    <switches>            
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="4"/>         
    </switches>    
  </system.diagnostics>
```

when I see C:\Users\jaime\AppData\Local\Temp\ folder, I can check that when that web service method is called, a folder is created with some files in it, so, it is not a permission issue.

What else can I do as another attempt?

By the way, when using SoapUI application, the method works well, so, it is not a problem of the WS.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting a try catch around the method call to see if you could view the InnerException to get more information

```
try
{
    var seed = new Seed.CrSeedClient();
    string semilla = await seed.getSeedAsync();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var details = e.InnerException;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that no exception is thrown... as I wrote, the debug window shows the exception, but the method call itself does not throw the exception, so it is not "catched".

Comment: @jstuardo Maybe try cleaning out the bin and obj folders and restoring nuget packages. Maybe it is just a weird VS referencing error. I also found some references [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3bb56b09-5b6e-4d74-aa0f-7ec03eb591a4/systemiofilenotfoundexception-is-happening-on-debug?forum=csharpgeneral) that might help you. They say you could use a Process Monitor to find what file could be missing [monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)